# C# : The concept of Thread and Multi Thread

Tags: c#

I have been working on some code for a while. And I had a question:

What's "Thread" and "Multi Thread" means in C# ?
What is the role of Threads ?

Comment: Thats a very generic and fundamental question. Search for this in Google and I am sure you will get a lot of information on this.

Comment: This question has been answered so many times in so many great ways, please atleast try to google it first.

Comment: Read all about it: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 1):

A thread is a sequence of instructions executed within the context of a process. MultiThreading is achieved when a  program uses multiple execution threads allowing each thread to share the CPU concurrently depending on the priority assigned to these threads.

You can refer this code for learning threading

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Alpha
{

   // This method that will be called when the thread is started
   public void Beta()
   {
      while (true)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Alpha.Beta is running in its own thread.");
      }
   }
};

public class Simple
{
   public static int Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Thread Start/Stop/Join Sample");

      Alpha oAlpha = new Alpha();

      // Create the thread object, passing in the Alpha.Beta method
      // via a ThreadStart delegate. This does not start the thread.
      Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oAlpha.Beta));

      // Start the thread
      oThread.Start();

      // Spin for a while waiting for the started thread to become
      // alive:
      while (!oThread.IsAlive);

      // Put the Main thread to sleep for 1 millisecond to allow oThread
      // to do some work:
      Thread.Sleep(1);

      // Request that oThread be stopped
      oThread.Abort();

      // Wait until oThread finishes. Join also has overloads
      // that take a millisecond interval or a TimeSpan object.
      oThread.Join();

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Alpha.Beta has finished");

      try 
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Try to restart the Alpha.Beta thread");
         oThread.Start();
      }
      catch (ThreadStateException) 
      {
         Console.Write("ThreadStateException trying to restart Alpha.Beta. ");
         Console.WriteLine("Expected since aborted threads cannot be restarted.");
      }
      return 0;
   }
}
```